# My form is invalid but my (ngSubmit) is calling the function

Tags: angular

I have one formGroup and inside i have one submit button:

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
   <input type="text" formControlName="name">
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When my component init i call this function to build the form:

```
buildForm() {
  this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  });
}
```

When i don't fill the input and click in the button, my component is calling the `submitForm()`.
I put a `console.log(myGroup.valid)` and it is `false`, but still calls the `(ngSubmit)` event.

I have other components and seems that when the form is invalid, Angular automatically don't call the submit function when the user click in the submit button.
I don't know if i'm forgetting something to Angular do this automatic check, or i really need to do something like in my submit function, like:

```
if(this.myGroup.valid) {}
```

Comment: How about disabling the submit button if the form is invalid?

Comment: Either disable the button with `[disabled]="!myGroup.valid"` or check if the form is valid in `submitForm()`

Comment: seems good, but i'm still curious about how this seems to work in some components and in others is calling the submit function when form is invalid

Comment: Hm, you could try initialising the control as `new FormControl('', { validators: Validators.required, updateOn: 'change' })`, but that would be curious if it worked in some components and in some others it didn't.

Comment: Either way disabling the button if your form isn't valid is good practice, so I'd go with that

Answer (score 3):

The most likely reason for you to see different behavior from your forms in different components is use of both template forms and reactive forms in your project.  The [Angular Forms Introduction](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) describes the key differences between the two form types.

As other commenters have suggested, with reactive forms you will need to disable your submit button until the form data is valid.

What has yet to be mentioned is that when you include `(ngSubmit)` in your form tag it also allows submitting the form with the enter key.  So, even if your submit button is disabled invalid form values can be submitted when the user clicks enter.

There are a few ways to fix this.

---

### First Approach

Add validation to the `(ngSubmit)` definition.

```
<form [formGroup]="myGroup" (ngSubmit)="myGroup.valid && submitForm()">
```

This will prevent your submission logic from running when the submit button is clicked or when the enter key is pressed.

---

### Second Approach

Disable the submit button in the template and double check input in the component.

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="!myGroup.valid">Submit</button>
```

When form data is invalid you can easily abort the action and optionally do some logging or other logic.

```
submitForm() {
  if (!myGroup.valid) { 
    // Optionally send a message to your logging service
    return; 
  }
  // Your form submission logic
}
```

---

### Third Approach

The other option is to remove `(ngSubmit)` from your form tag, then remove `type="submit"` from your submit button and add `(click)` to your submit button.

```
<button [disabled]="!myGroup.valid" (click)="myGroup.valid && submitForm()">Submit</button>
```

This removes the ability to submit the form with the enter key, which may be desirable in some cases but not in others.

When logging into an application users probably expect to be able to press enter to submit their credentials.  On pages that may have multiple forms it may become confusing exactly which form the enter key is triggering.

This option still double checks that the form is valid in the `(click)` expression since it is easy for a savvy user to enable buttons on your page with browser tools and submit an invalid form.

---

### Conclusion

Simply disabling the submit button is not enough, but is good practice.
Verifying data should always be done with code, whether it is a simple expression in the template, or included in the component logic.

If you don't need to do anything more than validate the form before submitting then the expression in the template (first approach) is perfect.

The second approach will allow you to add more logic, like logging, when a user submits an invalid form.

Answer (score 1):

Do not start with an enabled button, I prefer to not show any button until validation is good.

You can hook up a change listener like this:

```
fromGroup.changes(changes=>{
  if (changes=="VALID"){ showMyButton(); }
})
```